# Regular expression matching specific letter combos

Tags: regex

I need to match the following example strings:

LA20517505
BN30116471

I tried this: `[LA|BN].\d{8}`

That does indeed match, but it also matches other letters as well. I specifically need to match "LA" or "BN" followed by 8 numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use brackets here but parenthesis : `(LA|BN)\d{8}`

**Explanation:**

```
(LA|BN) Match character sequences LA or BN
\d{8}   followed by 8 digits
```

whereas the initial regex `[LA|BN].\d{8}` can be read as :

```
[LA|BN]  Match either character L,A,|,B or N 
.        Match any character
\d{8}   followed by 8 digits
```